# Android Studio displaying FirebaseListAdapter change codes

Tags: android, firebase

i have a `FirebaseListAdapter` which retrieves all the `uid` from the user but i want it to retrieve the names instead.

i have two child. one is to store all the `uid` of the connected users for a chat, and the other contains their information such as names. how do i convert the retrieved values (uid) into names and display it as shown below.

i have attached a snippet of how my app looks like currently and i want it to show names instead of `uid`.

```
    FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(getActivity(), String.class, R.layout.fragment_chatfprow, mDatabase) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
            TextView text = v.findViewById(R.id.text1);

            text.setText(model);
        }
    };
```

i think there is something to do with these lines of code but i cant figure out how.

This is how my Firebase ListView looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a `model` class for `Firebase UI Database` with an empty constructor for example:

```
public class Users {
private String mName;
private String mMessage;

public Users() {}  // Required for Firebase

public Users(String name, String message) {
    mName = name;
    mMessage = message;
}

 public String getName() { return mName; }

 public void setName(String name) { mName = name; }

 public String getMessage() { return mMessage; }

 public void setMessage(String message) { mMessage = message; }
}
```

Then in `Adapter` creation you can do like this:

```
 FirebaseListAdapter<Users> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Users>(getActivity(), Users.class, R.layout.fragment_chatfprow, mDatabase) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
        TextView text = v.findViewById(R.id.text1);

        text.setText(model.getName());
    }
};
```

You can take a look here from more informations: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md